# Is it possible to install Win7 + Snow Leopard + Ubuntu on PC?

Tags: operating-system

Is it possible to have Windows 7, Snow Leopard and Ubuntu on the same PC? 
Note that i have an Acer 5742 (i5 CPU 480M 2.67 GHz, RAM 3GB, HD 750GB).

Comment: Please recheck the [faq] for what is on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu and win7 can run on your machine, but installing OS X on normal pc is illegal as you should just install on MACs. Other hand, if you really need mac to see performance you need to use efi (http://refit.sourceforge.net/) on Intel architecture. And you need to do lot of things manually (i.e. setting up CPU speed etc..). After installing EFI you would be able to install MAC but after you can have driver problems as well.